# Get iso file from virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, fedora, iso-image

I have VMWare inside which I am running fedora.
I want to make a copy of this virtual machine .iso file -
so that I can run this image on another computer.
e.g.
[image]

Basically I want to run instance of this Fedora on
other VMWare on other machine.
Where can I locate the .iso file to which
this instance of virtual machine corresponds,
so that I can copy it?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean iso? Or a disk image?

Comment: @IshiTatsuyuki: Honestly I don't know what. The thing is like I said I have some things installed in side that fedora (shown on the screen). Now I need to make a copy of that so that others could use exactly that version of fedora from my VMWare

Comment: Disk image for sure. Check your user data folder for a folder called "Virtual Machines" or similar. Otherwise this type of software often has an export function.

Comment: @snoopen: can't find export button. But there is folder `Virtual Machines` inside it is `Fedora` - but inside fedora there are million files, which is the disk image? the files have vmdk, vmx, etc. extensions ..

Comment: You will need the whole folder. The different files are config files, the disk image and other machine state info.

Comment: @snoopen: So I just copy the whole folder called "Fedora" inside the Virtual machines folder? Ok After I copy how do I load the copy again inside the VMWare?

Comment: @snoopen: How do I make a copy - just copy whole folder? How do I access the copy in VMWare then? How to use the copy now ...